# Program stops working after a minute

Tags: led

I have made this small program to lighten up in sequence 8 LEDs, it starts fine, but it stops working after a minute or so and the first 2 LEDs stay permanently ON, its like the chip stoped, here is the code :

```
// Initialize an array with all 8 leds
// and give them the corresponding
// digital number.
const byte led[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};


// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {

  // initialize all 8 digital I/O pins as outputs.
  for (byte i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    pinMode(led[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void left (void);
void right (void);

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {

  right();
  left();

}


void left (void) {
  for (byte i = 0; i<9; i++) {
    digitalWrite(led[i], HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(led[i], LOW);
  }
}

void right (void) {
  for (byte i = 8; i>0; i--) {
    digitalWrite(led[i], HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(led[i], LOW);
  }
}
```

I am using a very old arduino duemilanove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had several problems with your loop conditions.  Arrays are 0 indexed. If we declare `const byte led[8]`, `led[0]` is the first element and `led[7]` is the 8th and last element.

Also, in `void right()`, you declared `i` as a `byte` which is an 8-bit, unsigned number from 0 to 255. While you wrote the conditional to be `i>0`, it needs to be `i>-1` or `i>=0`. So, if we change the coditional and keep `i` as a `byte` the loop would decrement `i` like 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,255,254... forever.  So instead, `i` should be declared as a `char` which is an 8-bit, signed number from -128 to 127.

```
// Initialize an array with all 8 leds
// and give them the corresponding
// digital number.
const byte led[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize all 8 digital I/O pins as outputs.
  for (byte i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    pinMode(led[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void left (void);
void right (void);

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  right();
  left();
}

void left (void) {
  for (byte i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    digitalWrite(led[i], HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(led[i], LOW);
  }
}

void right (void) {
  for (char i = 7; i>=0; i--) {
    digitalWrite(led[i], HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(led[i], LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 even though Peter said it above, until I saw `8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,255,254...` the penny hadn't dropped.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop conditions aren't quite right, which could be resulting in undefined behaviour. I highly doubt it would cause it to stop working spontaneously, but it's possible in theory.

In each loop that counts upwards, you basically need to stop *before* the counter reaches 8. For example:

```
for (byte i = 0; i<8; i++) ...
```

Note that it's `i<8` instead of `i<9`.

The reason is that the array is only 8 elements long, so the indices run from 0 to 7 (inclusive). Currently, your loops are going all the way up to and including 8, which means it's trying to read past the end of your array.

You'll need to fix that in `setup()` and `left()`.

The loop that goes downwards in `right()` is a little more difficult. At the moment, it runs through indices 8 to 1, meaning it has the same problem of reading past the array. However, it also never actually reaches index 0.

It's harder to fix because `byte` is an unsigned type, so you can't use `i>=0` as your condition (as it will never terminate). Personally, I would rewrite the loop to count upwards, but then reverse the index order inside the loop, so that 0 becomes 7, and so on. For example:

```
for (byte i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    digitalWrite(led[7-i], HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(led[7-i], LOW);
}
```

Like I said, I doubt this will actually solve your problem. It's worth trying though.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, its fixed now, i just dont understand why i cant use byte if i do, i>=0, this way i never goes to 255 anyway and if does, it doesn matter, unless im missing something.
Here goes the final working code :

```
/*
  Blink
  Turns on all 8 leds in sequence back and forth.

 */


// Initialize an array with all 8 leds
// and give them the corresponding
// digital number.
const char led[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
#define speed 40

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {

  // initialize all 8 digital I/O pins as outputs.
  for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    pinMode(led[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void left (void);
void right (void);

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {

  // Turn off the buzzer on pin 13
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  while(1) {
  right();
  left();
  }

}


void left (void) {
  for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
    digitalWrite(led[i], HIGH);
    delay(speed);
    digitalWrite(led[i], LOW);
  }
}

void right (void) {
  for (int i = 7; i>=0; i--) {
    digitalWrite(led[i], HIGH);
    delay(speed);
    digitalWrite(led[i], LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah it will, in a `for` loop where the a `byte` is decrementing, if you use: `i>=0` then this will always evaluate to true. When `i==1` it will decrement to `0`. When `i==0` it will decrement (and rollover) to `255`. This wouldn't be a problem if you used `i>0` (or used a signed type), but then you wouldn't be using the `0th` byte because you'd be leaving the loop before `0` was iterated over, ie `led[0]`.

Comment: But then `i == 255`  will be false ?????

Comment: but `i>0` would be true :)

Comment: also, it would matter because if it did go to `led[255]`, that is pointing to another area of ram not associated with `led` and would be unpredictable